# bundle exec rake: command not found on Ubuntu 20.04 docker host

Tags: bundler

I have a rails app (using the ruby:2.6-alpine base image) in Docker with an entrypoint executing some "bundle exec rake" calls. It runs fine in Ubunto on WSL2 and did run fine in Docker on an Ubuntu 20.04 host until recently. Now it fails on the Ubuntu Server with

```
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

Entering the docker container and executing `bundle check` gives the following result:

```
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
```

Executing `bundle install` results in:

```
Using rake 13.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Using i18n 1.8.9
...
Using webpacker 5.2.1
Bundle complete! 113 Gemfile dependencies, 175 gems now installed.
```

As you can see, rake is installed, there is nothing to install.

Executing `bundle exec rake` from the same docker image in Ubuntu on WSL2 it just works as expected.

How can I find out why calling `bundle exec rake` fails with `bundler: command not found: rake` in this environment?

**Edit**
When I create my image with `ruby:2.6.7-alpine`, it works on both hosts (Ubuntu as well as Ubuntu on WSL2), but with `ruby:2.6.8-alpine` I get the error on the Ubuntu server while it still works on the WSL2 Ubuntu. That explains why it worked fine until recently: before I used the `ruby:2.6-alpine` label, which was updated to `ruby:2.6.8-alpine` recently.

Comment: It's not an Ubuntu image, it's an Ubuntu host. The image is based on ruby:2.6-alpine